# Streaming responses from Vertex AI endpoints

Tags: machine-learning, vertex, google-cloud-vertex-ai, vertex-ai-pipeline

Is it possible to **STREAM** a response from a Vertex AI endpoint?

e.g. i want to do something like this in python

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform

endpoint = aiplatform.Endpoint(endpoint_name)

predictions_stream = endpoint.predict(instances=[myinputs])

for batch in predictions_stream: 
   print("streamed batch", batch)
```

Comment: It seems not. I tried it with vLLM (https://github.com/vllm-project/vllm) which support streaming but had no luck on Vertex AI Online Prediction